# Create Video by Images in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My Link

https://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/6xs0rxjb/

Using a Javascript `for` loop I am trying to create a video by simple jpeg file.
I am not able to achieve this, any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 var Allimages = ["eardrum0", "eardrum1", "eardrum2", "eardrum3", "eardrum4"];
 var canvas = document.getElementById("video");
 var lengthofImages = Allimages.length-1;

 function imageLoad() { 

    for (var i = 0; i <= lengthofImages; i++) {

        canvas.style.background = "url(" + Allimages[i] + ".bmp)";

    }

}

imageLoad();
```

Comment: do you have any error ? According to your code I think you should only see the last image, maybe you shoud add a timeout. Maybe you should also check the path or your images

Comment: @oliv37  sEE JS FIDDLE. I WANT TO SHOW ALL THE IMAGE LIKE VIDEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a delay before displaying the next image otherwise you will only see the last one

```
function showImagesLikeVideo(index) {
    if(index < Allimages.length) {
        canvas.style.background = "url(" + Allimages[index] + ".bmp)";
        //show next image with a timeout
        setTimeout(showImagesLikeVideo.bind(null, index + 1), 300);
    }
}

showImagesLikeVideo(0);
```

For an infinite loop, you should reset the index to 0

```
function showImagesLikeVideo(index) {
    index = index < Allimages.length ? index : 0;
    canvas.style.background = "url(" + Allimages[index] + ".bmp)";
    //show next image with a timeout
    setTimeout(showImagesLikeVideo.bind(null, index + 1), 300);
}

showImagesLikeVideo(0);
```

Comment: @DineshKanivu I moved the **if** condition at the beginning, it's safer in case the developer call the `showImagesLikeVideo` function with a wrong start index

Comment: What do you mean by continue ? you mean show the first image again at the end of the loop ?

Comment: @olive   Ya olive ...i want to do start again the loop

Comment: I don't think so, recursivity is more suitable for this case